# <Classname>.prototype.<method> is not working with "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
class Student{
    constructor(name,roll){
        this.name = name
        this.roll = roll
    }

    intro(){
        console.log('name is',this.name,' and roll number is',this.roll)
    }
}

Student.prototype.introduce = ()=> console.log('name is',this.name,' and roll number is',this.roll)

let s1 = new Student('any name',12345)
s1.intro()
s1.introduce()
```

the problem is , that both intro and introduce are being loaded correctly into the Student.prototype , but intro method is printing out name and roll , but introduce is giving undefined at both places

any help appreciated. thanks !

Comment: It's the arrow function not binding `this` to what you need. Use a function instead.

Comment: You can read the post that has been linked for you on the top of your question.

Comment: With arrow functions, `this` is bound to `window`.